# Retaining values Java

Tags: java, oop

I am new to Java and am having trouble retaining values from main. I am using blue J as my IDE.

Anyway, I have two classes. A Driver (with void []main) and a class called Deck. The first time the program runs it runs with no problem and sets the values in the deck as they should be. It then goes back to the main thread (Driver) and presents the user with a number value for the menu. They press the key, I read it in and I call Deck again to present the very same values as before but my values such as my array's are empty this time around. They are initialized but empty even though first time around I used my setters to set values.

I am passing around the same object (Deck) from the main thread (Driver). Does anyone know why the values are not there when I run the second time despite using the same object and setting the values the first time? I would post code but it is not well organized and I have summed it up pretty well.

Also is this a Java principle that I may not be understanding regarding retaining values?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @AlexG we would like to see your code. Also it is adviced to not be offensive or rude to others on stack-overflow.

Comment: @PrototypeStark Okay I shall post the code. Also if you would like to explain how I was being rude I would also like to know that

Comment: "If you have nothing smart to say then don't say anything at all. I came here for support not your attitude.". All he meant was show us the code because we can't guess the problem/find the solution.

Comment: Well clearly he has deleted his comment. And to be fair he snapped at me "about not posting code". Anyway, my code really is a massive mess so if you could just tell me whether Java allows values to be retained when going from main thread (in my case, Driver) to another class (Deck), setting the values within this class (Deck), going back to main and then once again to that class(Driver) to retrieve the values set before. Thanks for your help

Comment: The answer is _yes_.  You can do with by writing code that retains values after you set them in a class. Just write some code that does that and you should be all set. Hope that helps!

Comment: @jahroy Thank you so much for the answer. Just to elaborate, you said "write some code that does that". In my case I have a global variable at the top of my Deck class. I have a setter that sets it to the appropriate value and then it leaves the Deck class and goes back to the main... repeating those steps mentioned above. Is this a valid way (in theory) of doing it? Thanks again

Comment: Yes. Based on your description, your code sounds great!

Comment: @jahroy Okay perfect then its something on my logic side I will look into. I thought maybe it was a Java thing. If you want to post your answer(s), I will accept. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know exactly what could be your problem. But you could try these:
1) Have you declared and initialized your variables inside the constructor? If so, then declare your variables outside the constructor so that they are "fields" for any object of your class Deck.

2) Break your code and check if the values  have actually been set in your variables in the object of Deck class. If the fields show null . then they must not have been set to the values.
To set them, you could do it using your constructor or create another setValue() method to set the values. So you call this method in main() and set the values.

But yeah, it would be better if you could add your code in the question.